# find and delete empty files in directory and its subdirs without find

Tags: bash, recursion

I am trying to make a bash script that finds and removes empty files in a directory including subdirectories, without using the find command.

This is part of the script using the find command but I am unsure how to convert this line without using find.

`find . -type f -empty -delete`

Comment: why you don't want to use find command ? You can use `ls -lR`

Comment: it is for an assignment so I cannot use find. how would I use ls -lR to locate an empty file in a directory and delete it?

Comment: `ls` command will list all the files in directory and sub directories. Read output using loop and then use `[ -s  file_name ]` fo check if file is empty

Comment: For getting file names in current dir `for i in $(ls -1); do echo $i; done;`

Comment: @Digvijay stop recommending parsing output of ls, [it's bad practice](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @oguz ismail how will it parse subdirectories ? And who creates a file name with `new line` lol

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
# enable recursive globstar matching
shopt -s globstar

# directory to delete files from
dir="/tmp"

# loop through files recusively
for f in ${dir}/* ${dir}/**/* ; do
  # check if file is empty
  if [ ! -s "$f" ]; then
    # remove file
    rm "$f"
  fi
done
```